# Exception on AccessViolation when trying to load library

Tags: delphi, dll, exception

I am trying to load a library in my Delphi project and this library can be in two locations. So to load it, I am using the following code:

```
  try
    FHandle:=LoadLibrary(('some\address'));
  except on EAccessViolation do
    FHandle:=LoadLibrary(('another\address'));
  end;
```

however, I am having a problem because it never reaches the exception, I got the error that there was an Access Violation but it doesn't try to load from the other address...

does any one have an idea of the reasons?

thanks,

Comment: LoadLibrary Windows API just returns NULL on error.

Comment: But what should I use to track this error and to have an exception to it?

Comment: If first LoadLibrary returns NULL (FHandle is NULL), call LoadLibrary again with another file name.

Comment: Why is this question protected? I believe @ChrisF has a good day

Comment: @RBA - it was attracting spam answers (now deleted obviously).

Comment: @ChrisF It seems that an awful lot of spam answers, on an awful lot of questions made it onto the site. I wonder if more could be done to block them at source. I mean, thanks for all the hard work dealing with them, but I'm sure you diamond mods would prefer to be doing other stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LoadLibrary` does not raise exceptions. It is a Win32 function. Consult the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms684175.aspx) and you will see that it returns `NULL` if it fails.

Your code should be:

```
FHandle := LoadLibrary('some\address');
if FHandle = 0 then
  FHandle := LoadLibrary('another\address');
if FHandle = 0 then
  // handle the error, probably by raising an exception
```

Another option might be to use `FileExists` to check which of your possible locations contains the file.

Answer (score 1):

To add to David's answer, if the function does return `null` i.e. failed, you can get the error with `GetLastError()`, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360.aspx

a list of error codes can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360.aspx

You can use the result from GetLastError to raise and exception yourself with a meaningfull exception type and description.